# MySQL Structure for tree with different types

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, tree, hierarchy

I've been tasked with building a tree structure. I'm inexperienced with this thing and was wondering if there's any glaringly obvious issues with my approach.

So I have a large table of files (and fields regarding regularly use data in that file) which must remain the same, and I'm creating a structure where there's folders, so folders can contain X number of files and X number of folders. But the files can have no children.

With the structure I was thinking I'd have to handle either a null folderId or fileId but other than that I think its okay.

Desired output is that the tree structure is to be lazy loaded over a REST API, so a user can click a node and Ill retrieve all its children using an ID. I'm not sure my design is ideal so I'm after some feedback.

I was going to build my table structure like so (sorry in advance for bad formatting):

**FileTable**

- Id
- Version
- File

**FolderTable**

- Id
- Name

**ItemTable**

- Id
- FolderId foreignKey
- FileId foreignKey

**TreeTable**

- Id
- ParentId TreeTable Foreign Key
- Item ID Foreign Key

Comment: Your question is not clear for me! It's better to add some example of your inputs and desired output.

Comment: @majidhajibaba Hey thanks for the comment, I've just updated my post now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of using just one table

**DirObject**

with the following fields:

- Id
- ParentId #Link to parent object -- parent should be of type 'Folder'
- ObjectType #Folder or File
- Version
- OwnerUser
- OwnerGroup
- Permissions
- LastUpdate
- FileSize
- Status
- Path

***Update:***

Since you will be needing a separate table for the files, try this:

**Folders**

- Id
- ParentId #Link to parent folder
- OwnerUser
- OwnerGroup
- Permissions
- LastUpdate
- Status
- Path

**Files**

- Id
- FolderId #Foreign key from Folders table
- OwnerUser
- OwnerGroup
- Permissions
- LastUpdate
- Status
- Path

Note:

Value of Path should just be like how normal directories work
\folder1\folder2\folder3\filename

This will help when you want to get the size of a certain folder.
your query will look like

`SELECT SUM(FileSize) from db.files where path like '\path\of\folder\%';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This approach would work but my table of Files needs to be separate from the tree, which is the main dilemma I'm having.